# doc file from asp.net / vb with header

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, doc, asp.net-1.1

I would like to create a doc file (MS Word 2003) from a page asp.net / vb (dotnet 1.1) that contains a header and footer.
I have managed to create the doc but how to set a header and a footer?

Is there any other solution? Like using template.

edit:

I user the Render function:

```
   Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)   
     Functionality.RenderToFormat(divSection, "application/msword",
     Functionality.GetPagePathUri(Request), "", "MyDoc.doc")
   End Sub
```

Comment: show the code that you used to create the word document.

Comment: the aspx page will be saved as MyDoc.doc Insted of been displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/)?

> DocX is a .NET library that allows developers to manipulate Word 2007
>   files, in an easy and intuitive manor.

However I don't think this is going to work in .net 1.1 (you really should upgrade if possible as 1.1 was released 8 years ago!)

Comment: it needs the dotnet 4.0 but I can only use 1.1 :(